# Having Trouble With Paths

Tags: jquery

I'm new to civicrm so I'm not totally sure if I'm using all the right language here.

---

Something seems to be messed up with the way civiCRM is resolving system paths. Causing jQuery to fail in resolving its own path and/or paths to some of the assets.

This problem is manifesting itself as a javascript error which causes various front-end features to break.

[image]

- I have attempted running the tools at: Admin > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and Update Paths. **No effect.**
- I've looked at `/wp-content/uploads/civcrm/civcrm.settings.php` the paths look correct.
- `/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/` is getting new files written, so I don't believe there is a permissions issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

That first error, "SyntaxError: expected expression, got "<" suggests that something in WordPress - a poorly behaving theme or plugin - is injecting text on every page load.  That'll screw up CiviCRM.

I would troubleshoot this by switching to one of the core themes (e.g. twentyseventeen) and disabling plugins (ideally on a test site if this site is already live).  Assuming the problem goes away, you can turn things back on to identify the bad actor.

Comment: Exactly, such as a footer code, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Directories and Resource URLs - both under Administer > System Settings

Comment: What exactly am I looking for here?

Comment: you want to check you have got all the paths set up correctly

Comment: Feel free to post a screenshot of your paths and the URL of your installation so we others can see if they look correct if you are unsure. A lot of times I'll just reset them to whatever the system things they should be and then make sure that the file paths have correct chmod and chown, etc.